# Convergence of a Sequence Involving arctan - Is my solution correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Here's my question:

> Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence where $(a_{1}) > 0$, defined as:
>   $$(a_{n+1})=\arctan*(a_{n})$$ for all $n$.

Prove that $a_{n}$ has a limit $L$ and calculate it.

Solution:

- Prove that x>$arctan (x)$ for all x.
- Prove that above we can conclude that $a_{n+1}<a_{n}$, since they are equal we multiply $a_{n}$ by $arctan(x)$.
- $arctan(x)=0 \space iff \space x=0$, and that doesn't happen here since $a_{1}$ is positive.
- Therefore, we can use the follwoing theorem:

  > Let r be a number such that $r \in \Bbb R$ and $0<r<1$, so:
  >   $$IF \space\space \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| \le r \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n})=0$$

Sorry for the last theorem - I don't know how it's named in English (I'm not a native speaker).

Is my solution correct?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: What is the $\arctan * x$? Does it states an iteration of composition?

Comment: Your last theorem is false, so your solution is wrong.

Comment: @Crostul can you please explain why it's wrong?

Comment: It is not true that $$\vert \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\vert<1\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$$  Consider $a_n=\frac 12 +\frac 1n$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you please see my edit to the post. I have corrected the theorem.

Comment: @Crostul please see my edit to the post. I have correct the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you intend $a_n$ as a sequence satisfying $a_{n+1} = \arctan a_n$.

<del>Your 'last' theorem is not correct. Consider $b_n = 1-1/n$. You can prove that $|b_{n+1}/b_n|<1$ for all $n$ but $b_n\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.</del>

Despite of this, you can prove that the limit of $a_n$ is zero. From the fact $\arctan x < x$ for positive $x$, we get $\langle a_n\rangle$ is decreasing (as you get). Moreover, by induction for $n$, $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ so $\langle a_n\rangle$ is decreasing and bounded below. Thus it converges by monotone convergence theorem.

Since $\langle a_n\rangle$ converges to some value (let it call $L$) we can take $n\to \infty$ from the formula given below:
$$a_{n+1} = \arctan a_n.$$
By continuity of $\arctan$, we get $L=\arctan L$. But as you stated, $\arctan x = 0$ iff $x=0$ so $L=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and explanation. I edited the "theorem" to be the following: >Let r be a number such that $r \in \Bbb R$ and $0<r<1$, so:
$$IF \space\space \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| \le r \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n})=0$$
Is it still not correct?

Comment: @Alan It is correct, but I don't know can we apply the theorem to solve the problem.

Comment: I see. The problem is that $r$ is not always smaller than $1$, since arctan can recieve the value $\frac{\pi}{2}$.